# get lowest value while using group by and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks has has about 50 rows. The table holds results from track meets. Here is the structure:

[image: Table Structure]

What I am doing is getting a top ten list for each event. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Times WHERE event='1600m' GROUP BY fname, lname ORDER BY time, event LIMIT 10
```

Each person can be on the list once per event. This works, but if you look at all the times for the 1600m below...

[image: all 1600m results]

you can see that `Kyle Rummens` has a time of `4:32:00`. The image below is the result of the sql statement above:

[image: sql statement result]

Kyle's time for that is `4:36:00`.

How can I make it so that it is a list of the top 10 fastest times for the 1600m `event`, each person can only be on the list once, and it is each person's fastest time

EDIT: I was asked to add my results in text not image so here they are:

This is the result from the above query:

```
fname  lname       event time     meetName             date
====== =========== ===== ======== ==================== ==========
Jeron  Tucker      1600m 04:09:00 Coaches Meet         2015-02-12
Chris  Hughes      1600m 04:27:00 Distance Chalenge    2015-02-10
Andrew Rummens     1600m 04:28:00 Simplot Games        2015-02-20
Kyle   Rummens     1600m 04:36:00 Simplot Games        2015-02-19
Alex   Southerland 1600m 04:52:00 Coaches Meet         2015-02-12
Canyon Schmerse    1600m 04:54:00 Arcadia Invitational 2015-05-12
Joseph Stone       1600m 05:08:00 Coaches Meet         2015-02-12
Teron  Tucker      1600m 05:09:00 Harvard Track Meet   2015-02-19
Little Jacob       1600m 05:12:00 Arcadia Invitational 2015-05-12
Connor Kleinman    1600m 05:54:00 BYU Invitational     2015-04-03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min(time)` for each swimmer to find each swimmer's fastest time:

```
SELECT fname, lname, min(time) as tune
FROM Times
WHERE event = '1600m'
GROUP BY fname, lname
ORDER BY time
LIMIT 10
```

No need to order by `event` too, since it's always going to be `'1600m'`.

Comment: This is why I _prefer_ DBMS' that complain bitterly if you use a non-aggregated column that's not in the `group by` clause :-)

Comment: @pax amen to that. There are 1000's of Q's here that exist because an error doesn't. MySQL should really require a "disclaimer" syntax that lets it through, eg `select * ... lenient group by x, y`

Comment: Thanks, query works well. let me test it out some more before marking you as best answer

Answer (score 0):

Using correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Times t1
WHERE t1.event='1600m' AND t1.time = (SELECT MAX(time)
                                      FROM Times t2
                                      WHERE t2.event='1600m' AND
                                            t1.fname = t2.fname AND
                                            t1.lname = t2.fname)
ORDER BY t1.time
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: the query returned zero rows

Comment: Can you please post your sample data as text?

Comment: like the image i attached but just as text?

Comment: Yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: Not the result. Your original sample data.

Answer (score -2):

Add the word DISTINCT after SELECT

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Times WHERE event='1600m' GROUP BY fname, lname ORDER BY MIN(time) LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @phprunner what output do you get?

Comment: nope. still doesn't have the lowest time for `kyle rummens`